# C# Source Code Formatting in array initializer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to enable C# source code formatting inside array initializers in VS.NET 2010?

```
Elements =
{
// starting from here source code formatting does not work
  new TextViewModel("PublicId") 
  { 
    Label = new LText("Fund Nr:", "de", "Fondsnummer"),
    Watermark = new LText("Please enter fund number...", "de", "Bitte hier Fondsnummer erfassen...")
  },
  new CheckViewModel("Juristic")
  {
    Style = "Radio",
    Default = true,
    Label = new LText("Juristic Fund", "de", "Juristischer Fonds")
  }
}    
// starting from here source code formatting works again
```

Am I missing some formatting option in Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#?

Comment: From your comment on my answer: "Snippet is taken from object initializer." -- any chance you could add more context? I've tried it with `var foo = new Foo { Elements = ... }`, and it's valid C#. It just doesn't look like it from your snippet.

Comment: Up to vs2013 the problem still exists also for arrays and lists initializers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a VS.NET "feature"

Answer (score 5):

It's a "**Won't fix**" at [connect.microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/625182/visual-studio-refuses-to-auto-format-array-initializer-expressions-that-span-multiple-lines).

But, as posted there by Microsoft:

> If others, find that this is an important feature, please keep voting
>   it up.

**Note** that this is only for *multi-line* initializers.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like valid C#. You're missing an array declaration after `Elements =`. It should be something like:

```
Elements = new ViewModelBase[] { /* ... */ };
```

Once you've fixed that, formatting might start working correctly. It does for me (but I'm using ReSharper).

Comment: Elements is array-compatible property (List<object>). Snippet is taken from object initializer.

Comment: Gotcha. In which case, the answer's probably: "No, you're not missing any options; Visual Studio can't format this correctly. Either file a bug on Connect (with more context) or install ReSharper, which works."

Comment: I have a bad history with Resharper. Tried it few times, but after its deinstallation VS.NET is like a breath of fresh air - fast and furious :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need a default constructor on your TextViewModel and CheckViewModel.

As far as I am aware that's the only way .net can do it. Also, I am assuming those two objects inherit from a base class, and your array is the same type as your base class.

Otherwise the objects created will be of type "var". The compiler throws a fit because the array would technically have to be of the same type "var" as well.

Also, the parameter that you pass to your object's ctors should be initialized in a property just like the properties Label and Watermark of the TextViewModel object, and Style, Default, and Label of the CheckViewModel respectively.

Comment: This has nothing to do with constructors. It is just a bug or feature of visual studio. VS.NET simply does not smart format array initializers :(